# Loading JXSGraph in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm using JSXGraph (http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/)
to plot a graph on my website with jQuery Mobile

I've got some trouble dealing with jQuery Mobile's AJAX Link, 
by default, an  link will automatically perform as a AJAX link
but that will cause JSXGraph some problem which leads to an empty box

My current solution is to add data-ajax="false" to the link

```
<a href="page.html" data-ajax="false">Page</a>
```

I'm using the following code to plot:

```
$('.type-interior').live('pageshow', function () {
    var b = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {boundingbox: [-5, 2, 5, -2], axis:true});
    var p1 = b.create('point',[-1,1], {name:'A',size:4});
    var p2 = b.create('point',[2,-1], {name:'B',size:4});
});
```

Is there any other solution? like totally disable AJAX link or reloading JSXGraph after page load?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JSXGraph with jQuery mobile you need to pay attention to a few things:

- Attach the pageshow event to the page div (the one with data-role set to "page").
- When using ajax links, include the JSXGraph-JavaScript inside the div with data-role set to "page".
- If you're not using ajax links, you can put the JSXGraph JavaScript anywhere on your page, but you still need to enclose the board initialization with a pageshow event. This is due to the jQuery mobile CSS which initially hides all the pages leading to a height and width of 0 of all child divs. After a pageshow it's visible and JSXGraph can extract the correct div height and width which are used to place the graphics.

You may find this bit of documentation http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html interesting for more information about jQuery mobile's navigation model.

This minimalistic example works with jQuery mobile 1.0.1:

```
<!-- main.html -->

<!-- head: include jquery, jquery mobile & jsxgraph -->
<!-- body -->
<div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="main">
  <div data-role="content" id="maincontent">
    <a href="page.html" data-ajax="true">Test</a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- page.html -->

<!-- head: include jquery, jquery mobile & jsxgraph in case of ajax=false -->
<!-- body -->
<div data-role="page" class="ctest" id="test">
  <div data-role="content" id="testcontent">
    <div id="jxgbox" class="jxgbox" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // or #test instead of .ctest
    $('.ctest').live('pageshow', function () {
      var b = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {boundingbox: [-5, 2, 5, -2]});
      var p1 = b.create('point',[-1,1], {name:'A',size:4});
      var p2 = b.create('point',[2,-1], {name:'B',size:4});
    });
  </script>
</div>
```